# Problema al subir archivos a mysql con ckeditor

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, ckeditor

Tengo un campo `null` para poder rellenarlo después que los demás en la tabla y no me deja.  No se que estoy haciendo mal.

Este es el código que inserta en la base de datos, lo gracioso es que al darle al boton me dice que se agrego, pero no es así.

```html
<?php
 
 session_start();
 if (!isset($_SESSION['user_login_status']) AND $_SESSION['user_login_status'] != 1 or
    $_SESSION['user_permision'] != "Administrador") 
    {
        header("location: login.php"); 
        exit;                                              
        }

 
 require_once ("config/db.php");
 require_once ("config/conexion.php");
  
 $active_ticket="active"; 
 $title="Prestamos | Simple Stock";
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
    <textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor"></textarea>
            
            <input type="submit"  value="Responder">
    </form>
            </body>
    

</html>

<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['editor'])){
        
        $text = $_POST['editor'];
        $query = ("INSERT INTO ticket (Respuesta) VALUE ('$text')");
        
        if($query)
        {
            echo "se ingreso a la DB";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No se ingreso";
        }
    }

?>
```

**config/db.php**

```
     <?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_login_status']) AND $_SESSION['user_login_status'] != 1 or
$_SESSION['user_permision'] != "Administrador") 
{
    header("location: login.php"); 
    exit;                                              
    }


require_once ("config/db.php");
require_once ("config/conexion.php");

$active_ticket="active";    
$title="Prestamos   | Simple Stock";
  ?>
<html>
   <head>
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor"></textarea>

        <input type="submit"  value="Responder">
</form>
        </body>


</html>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['editor'])){

    $text = $_POST['editor'];
    $query = ("INSERT INTO ticket (Respuesta) VALUE ('$text')");

    if($query)
    {
        echo "se ingreso a la DB";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "mecachis";
    }
}

?>
```

**conexion.php**

```
<?php

$con=@mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
if(!$con){
    die("imposible conectarse: ".mysqli_error($con));
}
if (@mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Conexión falló: ".mysqli_connect_errno()." : ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
  ?>
```

Esta es la DB de mysql el campo que quiero editar es `respuesta`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cúal es el campo en cuestión? ¿Qué error es el que te da? ¿Cúal es la extructura de la tabla en la base de datos? ¿Te asegúrate de que ese campo sea nullable?

Comment: Con esta sentencia **INSERT INTO ticket (Respuesta) VALUE ('$text')** no estas editando, estas diciendo que cree un nuevo registro solo con el campo respuesta, seguramente si alguno de los otros campos es una clave o no nullable te dará error

Comment: osea toca con update